# not able to convert string date format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm taking `date` from my `csv` file

```
Dim odateq As String = sData(0).Trim()
```

I am getting odateq as  `9/15/2015`

I want to convert this to `15/9/2015`. So I wrote code like this

```
Dim newdate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(odateq, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

And I'm getting an error like this :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

any help is very appreciable...thanks

Comment: Your ideas are not too clear. The "dd/MM/yyyy" bit is saying "I will accept only strings describing a date following such a format"; in your example it would be "15/09/2015". If you input a date with a different format (e.g., "09/15/2015") it would throw an error (mainly `ParseExact`) because it would be wrong (15 as month is wrong). Once you have converted the string into a `DateTime` variable (`newdate`), you might show this information in a different way if you wish. For example: newdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"). Understand these ideas and adapt your code accordingly.

Comment: PS: note that `DateTime.Parse` is much more adaptable than `DateTime.ParseExact`; the months/days/years have logically to be provided in the right order anyway, but no error would be thrown because of inputting "9" rather "09", for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code you wrote is using the wrong format; the date you have is in the format M/d/yyyy (month and day without leading zero are a guess because you did not specify it).

try with this one:

```
Dim newdate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(odateq, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

the format you set in the `ParseExact` was telling the function to expect a date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` like 01/05/2015 but what you have is not in that format.

after you parse the input date, to get a string with format `dd/MM/yyyy` use:

```
Dim dateAsText As String = newdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: sir i want to get date in d/M/yyyy i mean first date then month and year

Comment: that's ok, but the parameter you feed to `ParseExact` is not the output you want but the input you give.